# W3 Total Cache, HTTPS and Goog Analytics

Tags: wordpress, caching, ssl

I have a website, I've implemented the SSL functionability a few days ago.
Now the website is correctly reachable at HTTPS url.

However...

When I visit any page of my website, the URL shown in the navigator address bar is correct... example: https://domain.com/post/.
That's fine.
However, Google Analytics is registering those visits as webpages with another URL. Google analytics shows another url where the visit was done, and that url is in this example: /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/domain.com/post/_index.html_gzip

How can I resolve that problem? Where is the issue?

Things I've done:
1) 301 redirect from all old http url to all new https url.
2) Google Analytics property was configured, the url of the website was changed to HTTPS.

Thanks all for reading and hope to find a solution for this problem.

Regards,
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you included Analytics.

1) If the WordPress framework send the 'click' to Analytics in the back-end code, then there might be a problem with sending the wrong 'url' that is visited. (Have a look at PHP's [$_SERVER variables](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server); probably the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is sent instead of `REQUEST_URI`.)

2) If you manually insterted the embed code from Analytics in your template, the url detection is all done based on the url in the browser, so you would never see your own filepath info there, unless it's being sent.